# c# wpf - Can I get the coordinates to a pixel clicked in an image control

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have an Image control running in my MainWindow.xaml, I was wondering if I can get the X and Y coordinates to the pixel clicked from the RoutedEventArgs on the MouseUp event for the control? I don't need the color or anything at that pixel, I would just like to know where that pixel was. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try handling the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event:

```
private void image1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
    Point pos = e.GetPosition(image1);
}
```